Databricks Cluster Size
We have a below use case.
We are developing ML Development using azure data bricks cluster service's. Our data bricks will receive 20 GB size of dataset records and we are running our logic/algorithms against this dataset's.
We have to run every day once this ML algorithms against 20 GB size of dataset's. I'm not able to Identify the required cluster size.
I have checked while creating compute in data bricks available ML based GPU supported clusters but its cost more.
Please let me the best compute size to perform this operations.
Thanks.
Azure Data bricks compute size

For ML tasks on a 20 GB dataset, a Standard_DS3_v2 CPU VM SKU with 4 cores, 14 GB RAM, and 28 GB storage is suggested for lightweight testing. However, the optimal VM size depends on factors like dataset size and task type, suggesting memory-optimized VMs for large datasets, compute-optimized VMs for real-time tasks, and higher core/RAM VMs for faster training. Evaluate comparable VMs for CPU/GPU performance and pricing, considering options like NC_Promo SKUs for cost-effective GPU capabilities.
